# Линковщик выдаёт ошибку undefined reference to `_nc_stdscr'

Tags: ncurses, qt, c++, linux

Доброго времени суток.
**Суть проблемы.**
Используется библиотека *ncurses*. Программа собирается в *Qt Creator*. Система *openSuse 11.4*. Библиотека подключена в .pro файле проекта. Не получается скомпилировать программу. Линковщик ругается на функцию keypad(stdscr, TRUE), getch().
Выдаёт следующую ошибку: *undefined reference to `_nc_stdscr'* на все использованные функции.

**.pro файл проекта (часть, отвечающая за подключение библиотеки):**

unix: LIBS += -L/usr/lib64/ncurses6 -lncurses
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/ncurses6/ncurses
DEPENDPATH += /usr/include/ncurses6/ncurses

**Код программы:**

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    int ch;

    initscr();
    raw();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();

    printw("Type any character to see it in bold\n");
    ch = getch();

    if(ch == KEY_F(1))
        printw("F1 Key pressed");

    if(ch == KEY_UP)
        printw("UP Key pressed");

    if(ch == KEY_DOWN)
        printw("DOWN Key pressed");

    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Так `getch` - это ДОСовская или Виндовая ф-ция и определена в `conio.h`, которого под линуксом, понятное дело, нет. Поэтому нужно или реализовать свой `getch`, или заменить его вызовы на вызовы тех ф-ций, которые имеются в наличии.

Ссылки по делу:

1. [cyberforum](http://www.cyberforum.ru/c-linux/thread139606.html)
2. [codenet](http://forum.codenet.ru/q29717/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D0%B2+Linux+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E+getch()%3F)
3. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux)

**UPD**: по ходу дела я неправ. Оказывается, в ncurses есть [`getch`](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/curs_getch.3.asp). Получается, нужно проверить командную строку. А именно две вещи. Первая - действительно ли подключается библиотека ncurses к проекту. Второе - подключается ли та версия библиотеки. Потому что, их как минимум две должно быть: 32bit и 64bit. У [ребят вот](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/several-undefined-reference-to-error-when-compiling-a-c-programm-186781/) скомпилировать получилось.

Comment: Устанавливал версию библиотеки 64 bit.
Вот вывод консоли Qt Creator'a:
Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -w
make: Entering directory `/home/.../.../Test_ncurse-build-desktop'
g++ -m64 -o Test_ncurse main.o    -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib64/ncurses6 -lncurses -lQtCore -L/usr/lib64 -lpthread 
main.o: In function `main':
/home/.../.../Test_ncurse-build-desktop/../Test_ncurse/main.cpp:99: undefined reference to `_nc_stdscr'
/home/.../.../Test_ncurse-build-desktop/../Test_ncurse/main.cpp:103: undefined reference to `_nc_stdscr'

Comment: Попробуйте слинковать с `ncursesw`, т.е. ключ компиляции будет `-lncursesw` вместо `-lncurses`

Comment: Увы, нет. Всё осталось как было.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте добавить еще `-lncurses++`

Comment: Без изменений.

Comment: Тогда только одна идея. Качайте ncurses-devel, собирайте примеры и сравнивайте в чем разница с Вашим проектом.